# SSRS 2008 (not R2) Group by multiple columns from multiple tables without duplicate fields

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm really new to SQL\SSRS, and have been learning as I go along. I know what a given report needs to do, so I fiddle about until it does that, with extensive googling along the way, so please go gently!

The report I'm having issues with pulls through data from 4 different tables in our ERP. Basically it's a stock control report. We want a list of items that have reached the minimum stock threshold (Item table), how much stock there is (Inventory, which is a sum of Quantity from ILE table), how much stock is currently assigned to a sales order (sum of Quantity from Sales Line table) and how much is assigned to a production order (sum of Quantity from Prod Order table).

For those items that have associated PO and SO quantities, we want to list the PO/SO numbers.

This is my script:

```
SELECT i.[No_],
       i.[Description],
       i.[Global Dimension 2 Code],
       i.[Base Unit of Measure],
       ILE.Inventory,
       pl.POQty,
       pl.[Prod_ Order No_],
       sl.SOQty,
       sl.[Document No_]
FROM [TEST JANUARY 2016$Item] i
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [Item No_], SUM([Quantity]) AS Inventory
    FROM [TEST JANUARY 2016$Item Ledger Entry]
    GROUP BY [Item No_]
) ILE ON i.[No_] = ILE.[Item No_]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [Item No_], [Prod_ Order No_], SUM([Remaining Quantity]) AS POQty
    FROM [TEST JANUARY 2016$Prod_ Order Line]
    WHERE [status] = '3'
    GROUP BY [Item No_],
             [Prod_ Order No_]
) pl ON i.[No_] = pl.[Item No_]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [No_], [Document No_], SUM([Outstanding Quantity]) AS SOQty
    FROM [TEST JANUARY 2016$Sales Line]
    WHERE [Document Type] = '1'
    GROUP BY [No_],
             [Document No_]
) sl ON i.[No_] = sl.[No_]
WHERE i.[Minimum Order Quantity] NOT IN ('0.00000000000000000000')
    AND i.[Inventory Posting Group] = 'PCM'
    AND i.[Product Group Code] = 'PCM'
GROUP BY i.[No_],
         i.[Description],
         i.[Global Dimension 2 Code],
         i.[Base Unit of Measure],
         ILE.Inventory,
         pl.POQty,
         pl.[Prod_ Order No_],
         sl.SOQty,
         sl.[Document No_],
         i.[Minimum Order Quantity]
HAVING (SUM(ILE.[Inventory])) <= i.[Minimum Order Quantity]
```

So. If I just have the sums of the quantities, then it's fine, because that's just one line per item. And when initially I just wanted PO references, that was fine - I just put PO Qty/Reference at the end and grouped (or merged cells, tried both) all the way up to that end, where it splits the quantities into their respective PO numbers.

However, as soon as I add in the SO ref too, then I get duplicates - say there are 6 PO's on the item, but only one SO, the report will have 6 lines - 6 unique PO's but the same SO 6 times. Complete with Quantity, which completely skews the Total, obviously.

If there's 3 PO's and 3 SO's, I get 9 lines. Each PO has a line with each SO on it.

I've tried grouping down to the SO in SSRS, but then I still get the same output... just with each 'set' grouped.

I think it's an SSRS Groups 'issue' (fully aware it's my lack of knowledge, not the software!) - I just want to have the same output as I had for PO's/Quantities, in a nice little list of them at the end, AND in the last two columns I want a nice little list of SO's/Quantities too. With each column having its respective total.

I'm not even sure that I've set up the row groups that I've already got right - I've started by grouping by Item (col1), then child group col2, then child group col3 and so on right up to the end, where the last 4 columns are PO/POQty/SO/SOQty but those aren't grouped. I think maybe I'm doing groups completely wrong? Don't even know where to begin with column groups :-|

Comment: First, you group by Minimum_order.. when you are not selecting it. Second, what do you want to get between the 3 so and 3 po's? which one do you wanna keep? If it doesn't matter, select them with max(column) and remove them from the group by

Comment: I had to put Min_Order in GROUP BY, otherwise I get an error: Column 'TEST JANUARY 2016$Item.Minimum Order Quantity' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Then use having MAX(.Minimum Order Quantity) instead of containing it in the group by

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your second question - I want to keep all SO's and PO's - but I only want one of each, whereas now, I get each one 3 times.

Comment: Sorry again - I should also have said that in my actual report, the Min and Max quantities are actually selected, along with a couple of other fields that aren't important. I just wanted to make the script a bit shorter to post!

Comment: And I don't understand how to use MAX in my scenario? I used HAVING because I only want to return items that have an inventory (a big long table made of up stock movements where the sum of the entire 12000 odd rows is the current inventory level) is less than the minimum order quantity. MAX seems to get the largest value in the table?